# The while conditional loop doesn't save itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

First, I just want to say I recently started with programming, so I'm not very good. This is my problem:

```
x = int(input("Write a number between 1-100: "))
while x > 100:
    x = int(input("The number must be less than 101: "))
while x < 1:
    x = int(input("The number must be higher than 0: "))
else:
    print ("The number is:",x)
```

There's a way to cheat the code by doing this:

```
Write a number between 1-100: 101
The number must be less than 101: 0
The number must be higher than 0: 101
The number is: 101
```

I basically don't want the user to be able to write a number higher than 100 or lower than 1.

I'm sorry for the bad explanation but I tried my best and, one again, i recently started programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just do it like this:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number in the range [1, 100]: "))
while not (1 <= x <= 100):
    x = int(input("That number isn't in the range [1, 100]!: "))
else:
    print ("The number is:",x)
```

You can of course, use nested if statements to make your prompt more informative of the error as follows:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number in the range [1, 100]: "))
while not (1 <= x <= 100):
    if x > 100:
        x = int(input("The number must be less than 101: "))
    else:
        x = int(input("The number must be greater than 0: "))
else:
    print ("The number is:",x)
```

Remember that you can test multiple conditions at once!

Comment: I'm really sorry but I do not understand whow the (1 <= x <= 100) command works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Weriton It works because Python is awesome! :) Seriously I don't know why all languages don't have this. But anyways it's just the most intuitive way to write that while condition. In english, while the number is "not in between 1 and 100 inclusive", then you want to loop. That simple English translates very well to Python in this case.

Comment: Sorry but All that command is telling me in my eyes is that while 1 isn't lower or equal to x, and x isn't lower or equal to 100. Can you see what I mean here? Thanks again :)

Comment: @Weriton yes I can see what you mean because you are absolutely right. That's exactly what that while condition does. xD

Answer (score 2):

Use logical `or` to test both the condition in a single `while`:

```
while not 1 <= x <= 100:  
    x = int(input("The number must be in range [1, 100]: "))
```

This will iterate the `while` loop till the user enters the input less than 1 or greater than 100. You can also notice that, this will lead you to an infinite loop, if user keeps on entering invalid input. I'll let you figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: I'd just like to add an other way to write the wile loop: `while not 1 <= x <= 100:`.

Comment: @Matthias. Yeah, forgot that Python allows that kind of conditions. Will edit post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[In Python, unlike other programming languages, expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in). This means that you can write your `while`-loop just like this:

```
x = int(input("Write a number between 1-100: "))
while not 1 <= x <= 100:
    x = int(input("The number must be in the range 1-100: "))
else:
    print ("The number is:", x)
```